# No route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

お世話になっております。
下記の問題に対して知見がある方がいらっしゃいましたらご教示お願いします。

## 起きている問題

いいね機能を実装中にエラーが発生しました。

```
# _like.html.erb

<% if @post.liked_by?(current_user) %>
  <%= button_to 'いいね解除', post_like_path(@post), method: :delete, remote: true %>
<% else %>
  <%= button_to 'いいね', post_likes_path(@post), method: :post, remote: true %>
<% end %>
```

いいねボタンを押したときに起きました。
更新ボタンを押すと正常に`likes.count`が１つ足されているので（いいねされている）`Ajax`に何か問題があるのでしょうか。
また、いいねされている状態であると正常にいいね解除できます。

## アプリケーションの挙動

１、いいねされていない状態でいいねボタンをクリック
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]クリック
⬇️
エラー発生
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
⬇️
更新ボタンを押下
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]正常に稼働する

２、いいねされている状態でいいねボタンをクリック
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
⬇︎
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]正常に稼働する

## 関連ファイル

```
#likes/_like.html.erb

<% if @post.liked_by?(current_user) %>
  <%= button_to 'いいね解除', post_like_path(@post), method: :delete, remote: true %>
<% else %>
  <%= button_to 'いいね', post_likes_path(@post), method: :post, remote: true %>
<% end %>
```

```
#likes/destroy.js.erb

$('.like_button').html("<%= j(render 'likes/like' , post: @post) %>");
```

```
#likes/create.js.erb

$('.like_button').html("<%= j(render 'likes/like' , post: @post) %>");
```

```
#posts/show.html.erb

<% provide(:title, '投稿詳細画面') %>
<div class="row">
    <div class="title"><p>投稿詳細画面</p></div>
 <div class="col-md-2">
 </div>
<div class="col-md-8">
  <%= render 'static_pages/show', post: @post %>
</div>
<div class="col-md-2">
</div>
</div>
```

```
#static_pages/_show.html.erb

<div class="Allpost">
    <div class="showAllpost_detail">
     <div class="Post_image">
      <%= image_tag @post.image, :size =>'350x250'%>

      <div class="like_button">
<%= render 'likes/like' , post: @post%>
</div>
:
（省略）
:
```

```
#models/post.rb

class Post < ApplicationRecord
:
(省略)
:
 def liked_by?(user)
    likes.where(user_id: user.id).exists?
  end
end
```

```
#controllers/likes_controller.rb

class LikesController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery except: %i[create destroy]
  before_action :set_post
  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @like = current_user.likes.new(post_id: params[:post_id])
    @like.save
  end

  def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @like = Like.find_by(post_id: params[:post_id], user_id: current_user.id)
    @like.destroy
  end

  private

  def set_post
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
  end
end
```

```
#config/routes.rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'maps/index'

  root 'maps#index'
  get  '/signup', to: 'users#new'
  get    '/login',   to: 'sessions#new'
  post   '/login',   to: 'sessions#create'
  delete '/logout',  to: 'sessions#destroy'
  get '/test_login', to: 'users#test_login'
  post '/posts', to: 'posts#confirm'
  post '/post/create', to: 'posts#create'
  get 'post/:id', to: 'posts#show'
  get '/map_request', to: 'maps#map', as: 'map_request'
  get '/map', to: 'posts#map'
  resources :maps, only: [:index, :create]
  resources :users do
    member do
      get :following, :followers
    end
  end

  resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
  resources :password_resets,     only: %i[new create edit update]
  resources :posts do
    resources :likes, only: %i[destroy create]
  end
  resources :relationships, only: %i[create destroy]
end
```

## 環境

Rails 5.1.6
Ruby 2.5.1

Comment: `config/routes`の内容はどうなっていますか？

Comment: 返信遅くなってしまい申し訳ございません。 config/routesの内容について質問内容に追記しました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`likes/_like.html.erb`の

```
<%= button_to 'いいね解除', post_like_path(@post), method: :delete, remote: true %>
```

を

```
<%= button_to 'いいね解除', post_like_path(@post, Like.find_by(post: @post, user: current_user)), method: :delete, remote: true %>
```

のように修正してみてください（実際には `Like.find_by`の部分はモデルクラスに書いたほうがいいでしょう）。

---

ここで、削除したいのはLikeなので、LikeのIDを渡さないと削除のURLが呼べなくなっています。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。
Masafumi Okuraさんがご提案してくださったコードに書き換えたところエラーが発生しなくなり正常に動くようになりました！
ありがとうございました！！m(_ _)m